# How to reload current running app's SharedPreferences from external XML file downloaded from cloud

Tags: android

Currently, I have an app which is having the following SharedPreferences.

`sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);`

Our app provides a feature to let user save their configuration to cloud. We will save the following file to cloud.

`/data/data/org.yccheok.jstock.gui/shared_prefs/org.yccheok.jstock.gui_preferences.xml`

We also provide a feature to let user load the configuration on demand after downloading the XML file from cloud.

`/sdcard/temp/org.yccheok.jstock.gui_preferences.xml`

**I was wondering, during the middle of execution of the app, how can I make the app's sharedPreferences re-load, based on newly downloaded XML found in temp folder?  (`/sdcard/temp/org.yccheok.jstock.gui_preferences.xml`)**

Comment: I would suggest parse the settings XML and then re-write/overwrite the preferences using `SharedPreferences.Editor` in your program. Since you can't assert that every Android device is rooted, there's no guarantee that you can have access to put the downloaded XML Pref to the app's data folder.

Comment: +1. Universal and straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_FILE, Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
```

instead of

```
prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_MULTI_PROCESS